# use loop variable for calculation bash

Tags: linux, bash, bc, syntax

```
for i in {0..9} do
    T=$(bc<<<"8+$i*0.5")
    echo $T
done
```

I get :

```
syntax error near unexpected token `T=$(bc<<<"8+$i*0.5")'
```

I believe the problem is the `$i`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not `$i`, the problem is in your `for` construct syntax. You need a newline or `;` before `do` (if used right after the `for` declaration):

```
for i in {0..9}; do
    T=$(bc <<<"8+$i*0.5")
    echo "$T"
done
```

Or

```
for i in {0..9} 
do
    T=$(bc <<<"8+$i*0.5")
    echo "$T"
done
```

For clarity, it's better to use whitespace before the here string (`<<<`) (and similar).

Although not strictly necessary in this case, you should quote your variable expansions.